# sql query to find an output

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I use redshift database.I am trying to write an aggregate query to find out the top ten inactive atms from 3 tables.When i try to find the percentage of inactive atms to the total of atm status,i get decimal error.There are no null values for atm_status column.What logic can be used here to get the percentage of inactive atm to total count?

Count percent throws decimal error -`c.atm_status/(select sum(atm_status) from etl_schema.fact_atm_trans) count_percent`

**Input:**

```
select a.atm_number,a.atm_manufacturer,b.location,count(c.trans_id) as total_transaction_count,count(c.atm_status) as inactive_count,c.atm_status/(select sum(atm_status) from etl_schema.fact_atm_trans) count_percent
from etl_schema.fact_atm_trans c
inner join etl_schema.dimen_atm a on a.atm_id = c.atm_id
inner join etl_schema.dimen_location b on b.location_id = a.atm_location_id
where c.atm_status='Inactive'
group by a.atm_number,a.atm_manufacturer,b.location,c.atm_status
order by inactive_count desc limit 10;
```

**Output**

```
ERROR: Invalid exponent, Value 'e', Pos 6, Type: Decimal Detail: ----------------------------------------------- error: Invalid exponent, Value 'e', Pos 6, Type: Decimal code: 1207 context: Active query: 1580 location: :0 process: query0_125_1580 [pid=0] -----------------------------------------------
```

**Expected Output**
[image]

Comment: On which basis (data), we can identify that the atm is inactive?

Comment: atm_status='Inactive'

Comment: `c.atm_status` holds the value `Inactive` and yet you try to divide that field by something? What is exactly is the result of "Inactive divided by 2", for example?

Comment: how to get the percent of only inactive then?

Comment: Add another `COUNT`. Something like `COUNT(c.atm_status)/(SELECT SUM(atm_status)...`

Comment: ! tried yours but not working.Also throws same error - (select count(c.atm_status) from ... where c.atm_status='Inactive')/(select sum(c.atm_status) ...